# Are there any applications of Fourier series/analysis in General relativity

Tags: soft-question, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, general-relativity

I'd like to know if there are any applications of Fourier analysis / Fourier series expansion in General relativity ? I mean how Fourier transform has applications in Quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dealing with gravitational waves, yes.  A quick Google search came up with lots of hits, e.g. http://arxiv.org/ftp/gr-qc/papers/0701/0701008.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Fourier Analysis has many applications in Nonlinear PDEs, for example, Nonlinear Schrödinger Equation, a very often used method is Hardy-Littlewood decomposition, to get the well-posedness(existence, uniqueness and some kind of dependence on the initial data) of the solution. A good book is "Nonlinear Dispersive Equation" by Terence Tao.